# (mod) Rewriting Out of Order Parameters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to re-write parameters that are not always in the same order in a URL?

For example, we might have a url like

```
/products/type/animal/id/123456
```

But it could also appear as:

```
/products/id/ab123456/type/animal
```

Using a mod rewrite statement like

`/products[.html?]?(?:/id/([^/])?)/?(?:/type/([^/])?)/? "products.html?id=$1&type=$2" [L, NC]`

works fine for the the first example but of course fails for the second. Is there anyway around this?
EDIT:There are multiple key/value pairs (perhaps 7 or 8) so it would not be possible to use a universal /([^/]+)/?/([^/]+)/ type regex.

Answer (score 0):

Just write multiple rules that match each of the possible source orderings!

Comment: Fair idea with a couple of parameters, but there could be dozens of combinations. With only 2 parameters, 2 combinations. 3 Parameters, 6 combinations, etc etc.